# Bind IEnumerable to ViewModel in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, ienumerable

I have a table in my view that a model is typed to it.  However, now I need to change that model to a ViewModel (so I can Union other models on to it but one step at a time).  Currently, I query my model (which works) but now I need to figure out how to convert that `IEnumerable` to bind it to the ViewModel (in this case, it is `searchResultViewModel`).  I gathered what i would need to loop through each line in the `IEnumerable` and bind it individually (that is what the foreach loop is, me trying that) but I need to convert it back in to an 'IEnumerable'.  How do I bind the `IEnumerable` to my ViewModel but as an 'IEnumerable'?  I cannot find anyone else asking a question like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchResult(SearchOrders searchOrders)
    {
        var orderList = uni.Orders;

        var model = from order in orderList
                        select order;

        if (searchOrders.SearchStartDate.HasValue)
        {
            model = model.Where(o => o.OrderDate >= searchOrders.SearchStartDate);
        }
        if (searchOrders.SearchEndDate.HasValue)
        {
            model = model.Where(o => o.OrderDate <= searchOrders.SearchEndDate);
        }
        if (searchOrders.SearchAmount.HasValue)
        {
            model = model.Where(o => o.Total == searchOrders.SearchAmount);
        }

        var searchResultViewModel = new SearchResultViewModel();
        foreach (var record in model)
        {
            searchResultViewModel.OrderNumber = record.OrderId;
            searchResultViewModel.PaymentName = record.PaymentFullName;
            searchResultViewModel.OrderDate = record.OrderDate;
            searchResultViewModel.Amount = record.Total;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is my SearchOrders Model:

```
namespace MicrositeInfo.WebUI.Models
{
    public class SearchOrders
    {
        public DateTime? SearchStartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? SearchEndDate { get; set; }

        public decimal? SearchAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my SearchResultViewModel:

```
namespace MicrositeInfo.WebUI.Models
{
    public class SearchResultViewModel
    {
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }

        public string PaymentName { get; set; }

        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the model that is being queried is the order model:

```
namespace MicrositeInfo.Model
{
    [Table("Order")]
    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public string SelectedSession { get; set; }

        public string StudentCity { get; set; }

        public string StudentExtension { get; set; }

        public string StudentFullName { get; set; }

        public string StudentPhone { get; set; }

        public string StudentPin { get; set; }

        public string StudentState { get; set; }

        public string StudentStreet01 { get; set; }

        public string StudentStreet02 { get; set; }

        public string StudentUniversityId { get; set; }

        public string StudentZip { get; set; }

        public string PaymentCity { get; set; }

        public string PaymentCreditCardExpiration { get; set; }

        public string PaymentCreditCardNumber { get; set; }

        public string PaymentCreditCardSecurityCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Payment Name")]
        public string PaymentFullName { get; set; }

        public string PaymentState { get; set; }

        public string PaymentStreet01 { get; set; }

        public string PaymentStreet02 { get; set; }

        public string PaymentZip { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Package Id")]
        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public decimal Tax { get; set; }

        public decimal Total { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Order Date")]
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public string OrderIp { get; set; }

        public string StudentEmail { get; set; }

        public string PaymentId { get; set; }

        public int Status { get; set; }

        public string ApprovalCode { get; set; }

        public decimal Shipping { get; set; }

        public string STCITrackingClassCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: searchResultViewModel.OrderNumber = (what is being assigned to this?) and you should be returning searchResultViewModel to your view no?

Comment: `searchResultViewModel.OrderNumber = record.OrderNumber`?

Comment: What are your models for `order` and `SearchResultViewModel`? And _That code works. This is_ ??? did you finish the question?

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry I need to remove that.

Comment: Can you post the `SearchOrders` model and the `SearchResultViewModel` viewmodel?

Comment: @DCruz22, the OP has been updated.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You can use `var searchResultViewModel = model.Select(x => new SearchResultViewModel { OrderNumber = x.OrderId, PaymentName = x.PaymentFullName, etc });` but you also need `return View(searchResultViewModel);` (not `return View(model);`)

Comment: Thanks Steven I already fixed the return type but did not fix it in the OP.  Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: So what is not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you - with your help it is all working now.